# Send big string into socket

Tags: c++, string, sockets

I'm new with C++ and came to this problem. I'm trying to send big string to a socket. I've seen the similar questions on stack but could not found the real answer. For example these:

[Sending a long String over a Socket C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606349/sending-a-long-string-over-a-socket-c)

[Send a string with sockets in C++ (Winsock TCP/IP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649755/send-a-string-with-sockets-in-c-winsock-tcp-ip)

[C++ sending string over socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568215/c-sending-string-over-socket)

Most of them rely on fact that `send` would send the whole data in one call, or they would use `char *` instead of `std::string`.

Here is little code written in C:

```
int SendAll(SOCKET client_socket, const void *data, int data_size)
{
    const char *data_ptr = (const char*) data;
    int bytes_sent;

    while (data_size > 0)
    {
        bytes_sent = send(client_socket, data__ptr, data_size, 0);
        if (bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return -1;

        data_ptr += bytes_sent;
        data_size -= bytes_sent;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

and now imagine that instead of `const void *data` we have `std::string data`. The question is how can I move pointer into data like this `data_ptr += bytes_sent;` with `std::string`?

One way that I came out is to retrieve the row pointer of `std::stirng` save it in some `const char * var` then use that variable in the same way(`var += bytes_sent`). But as I'm new with C++ I don't know if it's the "C++ way" of doing this? Is this the best solution to this problem or is there better one? thanks

Comment: Why not call the function like `SendAll(the_socket, the_string.c_str(), the_string.size())`?

Comment: thats another idea of solution, thats why I said what is the best way to do this?

Comment: In my personal opinion, that's the simplest and most straight-forward way to handle it. You could create an overload that takes the string as argument, and then calls the shown `SendAll`. Like `int SendAll(SOCKET client_socket, std::string const& str) { return SendAll(client_socket, str.c_str(), str.size()); }`

Comment: So retrieving the row pointer from `std::string` and manipulating it is ok with c++?

Comment: With that said, asking "what is the best way to do *anything*" isn't really a good question here, as it's very subjective and opinion based. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: In the "best way..." I meant the way it should be done in c++

Comment: You can post answer and I'll submit as answered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is the best way.

You have to obtain a pointer to the data anyway, to use `send`, so just adjust the pointer as you see fit.

Something like:

```
int SendAll(SOCKET client_socket, const std::string& str)
{
    const char* data_ptr  = str.data();
    std::size_t data_size = str.size();

    int bytes_sent;

    while (data_size > 0)
    {
        bytes_sent = send(client_socket, data_ptr, data_size, 0);
        if (bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return -1;

        data_ptr += bytes_sent;
        data_size -= bytes_sent;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This is perfectly fine and idiomatic.

If you want to keep both versions of the function, just forward the string's buffer to your existing overload:

```
int SendAll(SOCKET client_socket, const std::string& str)
{
    return SendAll(
        client_socket,
        reinterpret_cast<const void*>(str.data()),
        str.size()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

This is the signature of `send`. It requires a pointer to the buffer. Although a C++ API would probably prefer a pair of [iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586495/what-is-an-iterator-in-general), rather than a pointer and a size, this is not really possible here, seeing that the pointer to the actual buffer is required. So, there's nothing you can do about it, really. You can just use the string's `data()` member function to get a poninter to the start of the buffer, and work with that. This should be perfectly fine.

[As suggested by Some programmer dude in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476251/c-send-big-string-into-socket/56476751#comment99542937_56476251), you could add a simple overload that facilitates this:

```
int SendAll(SOCKET client_socket, std::string const& str) {
    return SendAll(client_socket, reinterpret_cast<const void*>(str.data()), str.size());
}
```